# Beans with custom annotation not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

I am trying to find beans with custom annotations after startup of my spring mvc app, but am failing miserably :)

Bean with a custom annotation.

```
@Animal("Tiger")
public class Tiger implements Cat{

    public boolean evil = true;

    private int teeth;

    public Tiger() {
    }
}
```

The custom annotation

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE) //can use in class only.
public @interface Animal {
    String value();
}
```

Then I have a Zoo class that tries to find all beans annotated with @Animal after server startup

```
    public class Zoo implements ApplicationListener  {

        @Override
        public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {
            if (event instanceof ContextRefreshedEvent) {
                ApplicationContext appCntxt = ((ContextRefreshedEvent) event).getApplicationContext();

                System.out.println("Say hello to the family!")

                Map<String,Object> beans = appCntxt.getBeansWithAnnotation(Animal.class);

             }

        }
    }
```

And the Zoo is defined in my application-context.xml

```
<bean id="Zoo" class="com.app.zoo"/>
```

The println is being executed but beans.size() is always empty. 
Ie, no beans can be found.

Any ideas? Don't know if my poor animals are running wild or are simply dead. :)

Comment: Please give us a fully reproducible example.

Comment: Do you have any beans of type `Tiger`?

Comment: Lolz.. no I hadn't added it :) Just saw that too. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

That's not a Spring bean, it's just a POJO with an annotation. Annotate your annotation with `@Component` for what I think you are looking for.

Comment: Hi. Thx. It has getters and setters.. :) I just didn't copy the full code as I didn't wanna pollute the post. Anyways.. @Component didn't help. :(

Comment: Do you have component scanning activated?

Comment: Yes. 
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.app"/> But I hadn't added my Tiger to my bean definitions! :) Silly.. Now all is ok again.. Thx anyway.